# Avoiding error invocations after timeout command

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I am creating a simple Makefile in which I am running a timeout command that interrupts the actual command after a certain time.

```
timeout --preserve-status delay <command>
<next command>
```

However, when executing the Makefile it throws an error after interrupting the command instead of continuing with the next command. I am using

```
--preserve-status
```

in order to avoid the error but unfortunately that does not do the job. 
Has anybody an idea how to fix this (maybe something like a try-catch functionality with which I am able to catch the error)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. If you want `make` to continue even if this command fail, [prepend your line with `-`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html#tag_04_84_13_02).

Answer (score 0):

The `timeout` command will exit with the command status when it completes.  If the command exits due to the timeout command killing it, the return status will likely reflect this (and be non-zero).    So, if you're expecting that the timeout can occur, then you need to handle the return.  You can do this in two ways:   First, you can use the `-` in front of the recipe, as gniorf_gniourf mentioned, or you can simply append an `|| true` or equivalent at the end of the recipe, which will cause the recipe to always return success:

```
foo:
    timeout --preserve-status delay <command> || echo "timed out"
```